Filtering tables data by selection parameters
I am getting data in a table and have added to filters(uSERrOLEID,Status:ACTIVE:INACTIVE) based on these the data will be viewed to the user.

the first time the page is loaded , whole data will be displayed as both filters will be passed null.
after adding a filter either id or status , the data fill be filter .
selecting both parameters , the data will be filtered for both of them .

the problem I am facing is that once i select the id , it filters the data but after I select the status parameter, it automatically sets the ID to 0.
This is how the table looks like..
enter image description here
I want both the parameters to work together or separately but the value of either should not default to 0 or null .
And yes , I have tested the API on swagger it is working fine for all the cases, for reference userroleid is set to int?nullable  and status is boolean?nullable.
This is the method that is used for filtering
filterEmployeeRoles( userRoleId:any,isActive:any): void {
     let finaluserRoleId=userRoleId>0 ? userRoleId:0;
     let finalisActive=(isActive==true || isActive==false) ? isActive:'';
     
     // If both parameters are null, return all records
     debugger;
      if (finaluserRoleId ==0  && finalisActive == null) {
        this.service.getEmployeeRole(0,'').subscribe({
          next: (roles) => {
            this.EmployeeRoleList = roles;
            // this.toastr.success('All employee roles fetched successfully!');
            this.sortEmployeeRoleList();
          },
          error: (err) => {
            this.EmployeeRoleList = [];
            this.toastr.error('Failed to fetch employee roles.');
            console.error('Error fetching employee roles:', err);
            
          }
        });
      }
      else{
        debugger;

        // filtering based on provided parameters
        this.service.getEmployeeRole(finaluserRoleId,finalisActive).subscribe({
          next: (roles) => {
            console.log("res",roles.result)
            this.EmployeeRoleList = roles.result;
            // this.toastr.success('Employee roles fetched successfully!');
          },
          error: (err) => {
            this.EmployeeRoleList = [];
            this.toastr.error('Failed to fetch employee roles.');
            console.error('Error fetching employee roles:', err);
          }
        });
      }
      
    }


This is the HTML code
<div class="row justify-content-end">
                    <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
                        <div class="form-group local-forms">
                            <label >Search By Role</label>
                            <ng-select formControlName="UserRoleId" 
                            (change)="filterEmployeeRoles($event.id,selectStatusId)" 
                            placeholder="Select Role"name="UserRoleId"
                            [items]="UserRoleList" 
                            bindLabel="userRole" bindValue="id" ></ng-select>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
                        <div class="form-group local-forms">
                        <label >Search By Status</label>
                        <ng-select 
                        (change)="filterEmployeeRoles(userRoleId || 0,selectStatusId)"                          
                        placeholder="Select status" 
                        [(ngModel)]="selectStatusId"
                        [items]="statusOptions"                        
                        bindLabel="label"
                        bindValue="value">
                        
                        </ng-select>
                    </div>

